# Boot from DVD takes too long

Tags: system-installation

It takes over 15 minutes to boot from two DVD's that I burned from two different downloads  - DeskTop - from the Ubuntu web site using InfraRecorder. Then when I use the mouse to try to start something there is a time lag making any progress impossible. I get virtually no response from clicks of the mouse. Can you help me fix this? I was able to use Bodhi Linux on a live USB with no problems. I would be very grateful for a fix. I am using the 32 bit Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's just basic thing like the DVD read is too slow or something.
I suggest to use USB Flash Drive.it's much faster than DVD.

but maybe Ubuntu on USB is also still a little bit slow

Comment: Hello Tommy, I'll bet I haven't enough memory. I was just looking at system requirements. I haven't got 512Mb of memory so it's time for me to add more memory. Many thanks for your reply. I used a live USB but I would need 2Gb of memory for that. The live USB didn't work at all.

Comment: So your problem is your RAM ? not the capacity of the USB Flash drive ?

Comment: @PeterNolan You might want to try a lighter distro like Lubuntu or Xubuntu which have lower system requirements than the main Ubuntu releases.

Comment: Many thanks. I'm sure it's just a case of not having enough memory onboard my PC from 2005. I'll bet an upgrade will fix everything. I was studying the system requirements. I just thought that Ubuntu would run on the most basic spec PC's but I'm am mistaken about that. I am delighted now to know that my not having enough memory is almost certainly the problem. I hope to send the DVD I have to a friend of mine who has a much higher spec PC and Laptop and if all is well on his machines that will illuminate everything. Again many thanks for taking an interest in my predicament. Best wishes.